# Why does my android emulator fail when using a function to call the gallery?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an android application that would call the gallery so the user could pick pictures. But it returns to the precious activity with this error.

`The application Camera(process.com.android.gallery) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

I have enaled a camera for the emulator, added 64 mb to the sd card. and it still doesn't work? Though I haven't added any image files as I don't know how but shouldn't it work normally? It shows a black background with a title on top "Gallery" then it crashes.

The function works properly for my tablet when I made an apk for it. But the problem is, I couldn't debug the other parts of the application on my tablet so I really need to make it run properly on the emulator to solve the other issues. Also, I can't connect my tablet on adb as it is China-made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no gallery app on the emulator. So you have to run it on a real device.

Comment: Oh. How do I debug it then?

Comment: Use a real device or try installing the gallery app manually from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1966003